# Kivy Language Dynamic Checkbox List

Tags: android, python, checkbox, kivy

I want to dyanmically add checkboxes in Kivy languages. I know how to achieve this in python but unaware how to do so in Kivy language.
There should be a checkbox for each file in the below list:

```
 from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileSystemLocal
 file_system = FileSystemLocal()
 file_list=file_system.listdir(App.get_running_app().user_data_dir+'\\')   # this returns a list of files in dir
 file_list=[x for x in file_list if x[-4:]=='.csv']
```

How can I loop this Kivy? I assuming there should loop on the right side, since that is python code. But I have no clue how? Any starters can be helpful.

**Edit**:

```
class MergeScreen(Screen):
    result_label=''
    check_boxes={}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.name='MergeScreen'
        super(MergeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        b=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        file_system = FileSystemLocal()
        file_list=file_system.listdir(App.get_running_app().user_data_dir+'\\')   # this returns a list of files in dir
        file_list=[x for x in file_list if x[-4:]=='.csv']
        for file_1 in file_list:
            g=GridLayout(cols=2)
            c=CheckBox()
            l=Label(bold= True,font_size=20,text=file_1)
            self.check_boxes[c]=file_1
            g.add_widget(l);g.add_widget(c)
            b.add_widget(g)
        g=GridLayout(cols=2)
        l=Label(bold= True,font_size=20,text='Result Name')
        t=TextInput(font_size=25)
        self.result_label=t
        g.add_widget(l)
        g.add_widget(t)
        b.add_widget(g)
        g_options=GridLayout(cols=2)
        g_options.add_widget(Button(text="Okay",on_press=self.create_result))
        g_options.add_widget(Button(text="Back",on_press=self.return_back))
        b.add_widget(g_options)
        self.add_widget(b)        
    def return_back(self,btn):
        self.parent.current = 'ExperimentSelectScreen'    
    def create_result(self,btn):
        file_list=[]
        root_dir= App.get_running_app().user_data_dir+'\\'
        for key, value in self.check_boxes.iteritems():
            if key.active==True:
                file_list.append(root_dir+'\\'+value)
        result_name=self.result_label.text+'.csv'
        result_dir=root_dir+'results'
        if os.path.exists(result_dir)==False:os.makedirs(result_dir)
        result_path=result_dir+'\\'+result_name
        fout=open(result_path,"w+")
        # # first file:
        for line in open(file_list[0]):
            fout.write(line)
        # # now the rest:    
        for num in file_list[0:]:
            f = open(num)
            f.next() # skip the header
            for line in f:
                fout.write(line)
            f.close() # not really needed
        fout.close()
        file_create=Popup(title='Confirmation',content=Label(text="Merged File has stored at\n"+result_path)\
                ,size_hint=(.75,.75),auto_dismiss=True)
        file_create.open()
        Clock.schedule_interval(file_create.dismiss, 3)
```

The problem is how I can want to add check boxes if a file gets created, since the `init()` does run only once. I have restart the app each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically add widgets in kv language, except in the sense of writing something like `self.add_widget(Something())` in e.g. an event binding such as `on_press`. I don't think it's a good fit for what you're doing though, this sounds like a task you should do on the Python side.

Comment: Thanks @inclement. Inside what method of the class should do this? `build()`? The problem most of the code in kivy. So I add the relevant Screen in kivy language. How can I define it's layout from scratch in Python?

Comment: This is up to you and depends on the structure of your program, but remember that everything instantiated in kv language is still a python object. That means that for instance you could use the `__init__` of a class to create its children.

Comment: I am bit quite confused here. If I am defining the screen in python, is it not possible to add it in screen manager bykivy code.

Comment: Please the edit in the question now. In an app with only one screen, I can use `build()`, but how to define layout in another screen ?

Comment: Following your advice please check my code .The problem is how I can want to add check boxes if a file gets created, since the `init()` does run only once. I have restart the app each time.

Comment: Since file creation is at another screen, I can call a method that adds new checkboxes for each file not presentally in a list but the layout would go wrong.